How can we generate access token based on some Id along with emailaddress and password
Currently I am working on a task where I need to generate access token for a user based on user credentials(emailaddress and password) and some Id (e.g: subscriptionId ). As per my research there is no such provision to do so with the default IdentityServer behavior but I guess it can be achieved with add custom token generator.
Any help on this appreciated.

This question is similar to: Identity Server 4 custom token endpoint, get signingcredential at runtime. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To generate the access token based on client id password and subscription you could use the custom token generator, below is the sample code you could try:
AccountController:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Errors);
    }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

Program:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using IdentityServer4.Validation;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDb"));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(GetClients())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(GetIdentityResources())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddResourceOwnerValidator<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
    };
}

static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client_id",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("client_secret".Sha256()) },
            AllowedScopes = { "api1", "openid", "profile" },
            AllowOfflineAccess = true
        }
    };
}

static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile()
    };
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        var email = context.UserName;
        var password = context.Password;
        var subscriptionId = context.Request.Raw.Get("subscriptionId");

        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(subscriptionId))
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                subject: user.Id,
                authenticationMethod: "custom",
                claims: GetUserClaims(user, subscriptionId));

            return;
        }

        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, "Invalid credentials");
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> GetUserClaims(IdentityUser user, string subscriptionId)
    {
        return new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("email", user.Email),
            new Claim("subscriptionId", subscriptionId)
        };
    }
}

To get the token with the subscription id you can use below request format:
POST /connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password}&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&subscriptionId=your_subscription_id


There is no subscriptionId in RegisterModel. So how to pass subscriptionId in the request?

@SachinGaikwad In the above code, the subscriptionId is not part of the RegisterModel because it's not needed during user registration. Instead, it is used when requesting an access token from the IdentityServer using the Resource Owner Password Flow. let me know if you have any other concern or the provided information is still not clear or not working for you
